# React mapping requiring key to idx, not sure why my function is missing

Tags: arrays, reactjs, key, mapping

I am mapping over an array of objects and printing out a user based on search map.  The function works, but I am getting "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."   I assigned a key to the img and p tags - I guess the div needs one?  Not sure.

```
const renderUser = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
  return this.props.name === obj.name;
    }).map((obj, idx) => {
      return (
        <div className="cols2">
          <div>
            <img key={idx} src={`${obj.image}`} className="avatar"></img>< br/>
          </div>
          <div style={spaceStyle}>
            <p key={idx}>
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile Name">Name:</span> {obj.name} < br/>
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile Email">Email:</span> {obj.email} <br />
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile Flavor">Flavor:</span> {obj.flavor} <br />
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile STR">STR:</span> {obj.str} <br />
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile AGI">AGI:</span> {obj.agi} <br />
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile INT">INT:</span> {obj.int} <br />
              <span className="profileText" alt="Profile STA">STA:</span> {obj.sta} <br />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
```

Comment: Why are you shoving so many spans into a P tag? you could either use LI or make them all P and reduce their margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add a key to the surrounding, top element.

From [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.

```
const renderUser = this.props.data.filter(obj => this.props.name === obj.name).map((obj, idx) => {
  return (
    <div key={idx} className="cols2">
      <div>
        <img src={`${obj.image}`} className="avatar"></img>< br/>
      </div>
      <div style={spaceStyle}>
        <p>
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile Name">Name:</span> {obj.name} < br/>
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile Email">Email:</span> {obj.email} <br />
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile Flavor">Flavor:</span> {obj.flavor} <br />
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile STR">STR:</span> {obj.str} <br />
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile AGI">AGI:</span> {obj.agi} <br />
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile INT">INT:</span> {obj.int} <br />
          <span className="profileText" alt="Profile STA">STA:</span> {obj.sta} <br />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: thanks - works great.  I guess I just don't understand why the key is needed in this case.

Comment: If you create multiple React elements dynamically, you should add a unique identifier to it (`key`) so that React knows which one is which. You can pretty much ignore it, it's just to make React faster.

Answer (score 1):

The key should be applied to the outer element of the child - `<div className="cols2">`:

```
<div className="cols2" key={idx}>
```

You should remove the key from the internal `<p>` and `<img>` elements:

```
<img key={idx} src={`${obj.image}`} className="avatar"> -> <img src={`${obj.image}`} className="avatar">                              

<p key={idx}> -> <p>
```